# Anti commutativity of multicovectors

Tags: permutations, tensors, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $ \omega \in \Lambda^k(V^*) $ and $\eta \in \Lambda^l(V^*)$. Then

$\omega \wedge \eta = (-1)^{kl} \eta \wedge \omega$

I am trying to understand the reason for $  (-1) ^{kl} $ and i have understood upto the following

If $I$ and $J$ are increasing multi indices then ,

$ \epsilon^I \wedge \epsilon^J = sign \tau \epsilon^J \wedge \epsilon^I $

where $ \tau $ is the permutation that sends $IJ$ to $JI$

Then $ sign \tau= (-1)^{kl} $ is what I cannot understand.

I tried working out in the simple case of $k=2$ and $l= 3$

Then the number of transpositions required for (1,2,3,4,5) to (3,4,5,1,2) is only 4 and the result of each transposition is given below.

(4,2,3,1,5) (4,5,3,1,2) (3,5,4,1,2) (3,4,5,1,2)

There were only 4 transpositions required, while according to the text, it must require $kl=6$
transpositions. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your text says that kl=6 is *required*. The important thing is NOT whether 6 is the lowest number of transpositions possible but if the number is **even** or **odd**. Your text is probably showing you *a systematic way of rearranging $k$ terms $l$ times*. Like this

$\{\bar{1},\bar{2},3,4,5\}\to$$\{\bar{1},3,\bar{2},4,5\}\to$$\{\bar{1},3,4,\bar{2},5\}\to$$\{\bar{1},3,4,5,\bar{2}\}$

Now we have rearranged our first term. We have used 3 transpositions to move $\bar{2}$. Let's continue with $\bar{1}$

$\to\{3,\bar{1},4,5,\bar{2}\}$$\to\{3,4,\bar{1},5,\bar{2}\}$$\to\{3,4,5,\bar{1},\bar{2}\}$

Not surprisingly this required another $l=3$ transpositions.

There are $k$ terms being transposed $l$ times, hence $kl=2\cdot3=6$ transpositions all in all.

If you start by moving $\bar{1}$ you will end up with $8$ transpositions instead.

Comment: Thanks. I got it